Does there exist a power series which sends every algebraic number in its radius of convergence to a rational number?
Section 1.3 of https://swc-math.github.io/aws/2008/08BeukersNotesDraft.pdf claims there exists a non-constant power series $f(x)$ with positive radius of convergence $\rho,$ such that for any algebraic number $a$ with $|a| < \rho,$ the value $f(a)$ is rational. The author says a proof can be found in [], presumably meaning they meant to add a citation but forgot.
Where can I find a reference to this power series?

I think this is relevant (but I'm in the middle of something else now and don't have time to give it much thought): Functions that take rationals to rationals

@hardmath Thanks for catching that, edited!

Presumably you mean every real algebraic number $a$ with $|a| < r$.

Also, $0$ would work, so perhaps you want to exclude constants.

https://mathoverflow.net/a/434311/95172 looks like this works

@QC_QAOA This is good enough for me to be satisfied, but technically it doesn't apply -- note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}.$

@RobertIsrael Exclude constants yes, although I don't think the original source restricts to real numbers.

The algebraic numbers are dense in $\mathbb C$, but all rationals are in $\mathbb R$.  The only analytic functions taking a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb R$ are constants.

Given any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ of distinct reals, I will define a non-constant entire function $f$ that takes $S$ into the rationals.  This will be of the form $$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \prod_{k < n} (z - x_k) \tag 1$$
Note that for such a function, $f(x_j) = \sum_{n=1}^{j} c_n \prod_{k < n} (x_j - x_k)$, and given real numbers $c_1, \ldots, c_{j-1}$, there is a dense set of reals $c_j$ for which this will be rational.  We just need to ensure that the series (1) converges uniformly on compact sets: this can be done by taking $|c_n| \le b_n$, where $b_n > 0$ is small enough that, say, $b_n \prod_{k < n} |z - x_k| < 2^{-n}$ for $|z| \le n$.

Something is wrong in your equation at the start of the second paragraph, where $z$ only appears on the RHS.

Thanks (fixed it)
